# Laravel - Filter collection by checking if value exists in array in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to return a collection of posts, based on if a single value exists in an array stored in the table.

In my posts table, I have regular column names like 'title', 'body', and 'slug'. I am managing multiple sites using the same table, so I have an additional column name of 'site_ids'. When a user creates a post, they select what sites they want it published on and it stores the site id's as an array (eg. [1,2])

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Title         | Site_ids     | Slug         |
-----------------------------------------------
| Test Title    |[1,2,3]       |test-title    |
-----------------------------------------------
| Another Title |[1,6]         |another-title |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Now I am creating an API to return all posts with the site_id of 1. How can this be achieved? Here is my current code in my PostController

**API ROUTE**

```
Route::get('/{site_id}/posts','PostController@index')->name('Show Posts');
```

**Code:**

```
  public function index($site_id)
    {
        // Return all posts by id
        $posts = Post::whereIn('sites', $site_id)->get();
        return new PostCollection($posts);
    }
```

I am getting this error message

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the `foreach()` in this context? Is `PostCollection` a wrapper for a `view()`?

Comment: @TimLewis Its a Laravel Post Collection Resource https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources

Comment: Ah yes, that's my bad; didn't see API (bolded and everything); must be Monday. That aside, I thought `whereIn()` converted the second param to an array if it wasn't one, but the answers below seem to be correct to handle that. Does that query work though? I wouldn't think that storing literal `[1, 2]` would work with `whereIn()`...

Comment: Lol it is a Monday! The query is working now after I wrapped it in brackets. However its returning 0 items. Its like its not going through the array in my table?

Comment: That's what I was hinting at; the MySQL `IN ()` operator looks for the value of a column matching the values supplied, so `sites IN (1)` for example wouldn't work for the column value of `[1, 2]`. You'll need to link `sites` and `posts` properly, using something like `site_id`, or `sites_posts` pivot table, etc, then a `whereHas("sites", ...)` method instead of `whereIn()`. That makes this question a bit too broad.

Comment: Or, to handle this currently, you could use a `->where("sites", "LIKE", "%".$site_id."%");` to handle a wildcard text search (loosely matching `[1, 2]` to `1`, etc), but that's inefficient and not the best approach.

Comment: Sites and Posts need to have a many to many relationship with a pivot table.

Comment: Is `site_ids` a JSON column? If not: What versions of MySQL and Laravel are you using?

Comment: Its not a JSON column, just a VARCHAR.

Comment: If you are using MySQL 5.7+, you should consider switching to a JSON column (in combination with markantonay's answer).

Answer (score 1):

you can try whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(meta, "1")') something like that. check for the [command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) in mysql. and also if your running in 5.7 of laravel you might want to check [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1466)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for `whereIn` must be an array. You should do this:

```
public function index($site_id)
{
    // Return all posts by id
    $posts = Post::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(sites, \'{$site_id}\')')->get();
    return new PostCollection($posts);
}
```

Comment: So I wrapped the value with the brackets and now I am not receiving the error message. However it is returning 0 items. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated it, this should work. I have not tested though. But you will get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is likely to get a downvote but honestly this is what you're doing wrong:

> "I am wanting to return a collection of posts, based on if a single
>   value exists in an array stored in the table."

You should set up a many to many relation between Posts and Sites with a pivot table and then you could just do something like this:

```
Site::find($id)->Posts;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many